# Oracle EXECUTE immediate UPDATE

Tags: sql, oracle, dynamic-sql

I am just started to study Oracle. When I Execute Following Statement

```
DECLARE
  sql_stmt VARCHAR2(200);
  table_obj user_tables.table_name%type;
begin
    for l_i in (select table_name from results) loop

      table_obj := dbms_assert.sql_object_name(l_i.table_name);

      sql_stmt :=  'update results set cnt_record = ( select count(*) from :1) where table_name = UPPER(:2)'; 

      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt 
      USING table_obj, l_i.table_name;          
    end loop;
end;
```

I get an error:

Error report -

> ORA-00903: invalid table name
>   ORA-06512: at line 11
>   00903. 00000 -  "invalid table name"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only allow to pass constant names into an expression.  You are not allowed to pass table names, column names, operators, function names and so on.

So, you have to "munge" the query string before you execute it:

```
      table_obj := dbms_assert.sql_object_name(l_i.table_name);

      sql_stmt :=  'update results set cnt_record = ( select count(*) from <tablename>) where table_name = UPPER(:1)'; 

      sql_stmt := replace(sql_stmt, '<tablename>', table_obj);

      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql_stmt 
      USING l_i.table_name;          
    end loop;
end;
```

You could replace both occurrences using `replace()`, but the argument in `upper()` is fine for a parameter.

Comment: Thanks! And you can more in detail about "You could replace both occurrences using replace(), but the argument in upper() is fine for a parameter."

Comment: @GPlat . . . I'm making a distinction between the table being used as a name for comparison and the table being used in the `from` clause.  The first can use a parameter, even though the second cannot.